# Is the word tumultuous can be used in metaphorical way

Tags: word-usage

Consider somebody, a woman, is going to get married soon.

> They were tumultuous days and she had eclectic emotions lately about 
>   will having leave her family and the city where she has been living
>   all her life.

( I know .."will having leave her family.." part is probably grammatically wrong but I could not join the sentences properly.I mean here " she will have to leave and knows that")

Comment: In your example sentence, the "days" are plural, so it's "*They were* tumultuous days".

Comment: You wouldn't describe emotions as "eclectic".  If your point is that she's feeling *very* emotional, you might use "wild" or "chaotic".  If your point is that she feels both good *and* bad about leaving, you would says she has "mixed emotions".

Comment: For the bit about "will having leave", what do you mean by "having"?  Are you using it to construct a past tense? ("She has left.")  Or are you using it to describe an *obligation*? ("She has to leave.")

Comment: Also, I think you mean "metaphorical", not "metamorphic".

Comment: @StephenDunscombe I used the word 'having' to describe an 'obligation'

Comment: I am not sure that "metaphorical" is the right word either.  "Tumultuous" means "highly agitated" or "marked by disturbance and uproar".  Yes, days can be tumultuous, but that is not a metaphorical usage.

Comment: The construction you want is "about having to leave her family...".  I'd also recommend a comma after "family", though it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: @StephenDunscombe I wanted to use the word 'eclectic" in the sense of 'mixed emotions' to show great ambivalence she feels because her life is going to change sharply and she is not sure

Comment: The standard phrase there would be "mixed emotions".  If you want to exaggerate a bit, I'd go with "chaotic", or change the whole construction to "she was conflicted about..."

Comment: @stangdon I say "metaphorical " because only she feels in this way and the word refers to her emotions.But I am not sure it is still correct to use it in this way

Comment: *Tumultuous* is fine, as Stephen Dunscombe tells you. For the rest, try this: "They were tumultuous days, and she had [*better:* was having] **mixed** emotions lately about **having to** leave her family and the city where she **had** been living all her life." *Have* with the sense *be obliged* requires **to**; and since in your final clause you are talking about a time prior to the past time at which the days *were* tumultuous, you need a past perfect. There is no need for *will* to mark futurity; the context should make that clear; and *will* cannot be cast in a non-finite form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tumultuous" can be used to refer to personal disturbance as well as social disturbance.  If someone is having a stressful and chaotic time, they might well call it a "tumultuous" time.